# Include/Exclude L2 from RISC-V Rocket

Tags: riscv, rocket

How do I include/remove the L2 cache in the RISC-V Rocket chip? Is it something I need to change in the rocket chip's config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you do not need to change the file, just which CONFIG you use. Within [Config.scala](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/Configs.scala) you can see all of the configs, including the configs leveraging WithL2Cache. For example, say you wanted to use the DefaultL2Config. Whenever you perform a make command within rocket-chip, have CONFIG=DefaultL2Config. You can do this via an export:

```
$ export CONFIG=DefaultL2Config
```

or on each line

```
$ make CONFIG=DefaultL2Config
```